# Where is javax.jms.* in maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-jms

I am trying to add dependency to pull `javax.jms.*`

I tried many repos but none seem to have this. Any idea if there is a maven repo to pull this jar?

What I've tried until now:

```
compile group: 'javax.jms', name: 'javax.jms-api', version: '2.0.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.main.javaee-api', name: 'javax.jms', version: '3.1.2.2'
compile group: 'Javax.jms', name: 'jms', version: '1.1'
```

Comment: This link gives the exact artifact number and the group name https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms/1.1.  This lines didn't help ?

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the JMS interfaces you can use this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_2.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>    
</dependency>
```

This dependency uses the [Apache Software License, Version 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Or you can use this:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This uses the [Eclipse Public License 2.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/license/epl-2.0).